# my app is not responding when it should be asking for permission

Tags: kotlin, permissions, onclick, imageview

I'm coding an instagram clone and i must request external storage permission but my app doesn't respond when i clicked imageView that ı set onClick method (fotoSec) for taking image from gallery.

```
   fun fotoSec (view: View) {

    // Önce izin istenecek. İzin verilirse galeriye gidecek verilmezse uyarı mesajı gösterecek.
    // İzini bir kere verdiyse tekrar istenmeyecek direkt galeriye gidecek.
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //İzin verilmemiş.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)
    } else {
        //İzin verilmiş.
        val galeriIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(galeriIntent,2)
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if (requestCode==1) {
        if(grantResults.size>0 &&grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            val galeriIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            startActivityForResult(galeriIntent,2)
        }
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    if ( requestCode==2 &&  resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
        secilenGorsel=data.data

        if (secilenGorsel!=null) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 28) {
                val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver,secilenGorsel!!)
                secilenBitmap=ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                image!!.setImageBitmap(secilenBitmap)


            }else {
                secilenBitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver,secilenGorsel)

                image!!.setImageBitmap(secilenBitmap)
            }

        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

And there is no exceptions in logcat.
In addition I'm a beginner, sorry my faults.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that you have added the same permission in AndroidManifest.xml like below.